# how to create timer in linux in c language?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I would need a timer, so can you tell me how can I make a timer that would interrupt me in every millisecond, and then I would have a variable in which I would count the milliseconds, and then in every 20 milliseconds I would call the function in the main?

Comment: Perhaps you want to share with us what you have allready tried?

Comment: There seem to already be many related questions with answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [1ms resolution timer under linux recommended way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240058/1ms-resolution-timer-under-linux-recommended-way)

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing else to do then waiting for 20ms, then do something, then wait again, the following approach would do:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  while (1)
  {
    struct timeval tv = {0, 20000}; /* 0 seconds, 20000 micro secs = 20 milli secs */

    if (-1 == select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv))
    {
      if (EINTR == errno)
      {
        continue; /* this means the process received a signal during waiting, just start over waiting. However this could lead to wait cycles >20ms and <40ms. */
      }

      perror("select()");
      exit(1);
    }

    /* do something every 20 ms */
  }

  return 0;
}
```